# Or Where Between in Collection

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to filter a collection by two dates from and to, but the collection does not have the `orWhereBetween` or `orWhere` method, and as a result, I can't do it.
How to be in this case? Tried through the filter, does not work.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections

```
$startTime = Carbon::parse($explodeComma[0]);
endTime = Carbon::parse($explodeComma[1]);
$collection = $collection->filter(function ($item) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
    return (data_get($item, 'date_start') > $startTime)
        && (data_get($item, 'date_start') < $endTime)
        || (data_get($item, 'date_end') > $startTime)
        && (data_get($item, 'date_end') < $endTime);
});
```

Comment: You're mixing your AND/OR clauses. Put parenthesis around the larger clauses that go together.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = $collection->filter(function ($item) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
    return (
        (
            Carbon::parse($item->date_start) >= $startTime
            && Carbon::parse($item->date_start) <= $endTime
        )
        ||
        (
            Carbon::parse($item->date_end) >= $startTime
            && Carbon::parse($item->date_end) <= $endTime
        )
    );
});
```

Works

Comment: Nice! Glad you got this working  Out of curiosity, is this Collection constructed from a Model/Database Query? Could you pass `$startTime` and `$endTime` to the query builder instead? `->filter()` can be horrendously slow for large datasets, which is why doing this kind of filtering at the Database level is generally a better approach.

Comment: ```$collection = (new Company())->newCollection();
        foreach($newCompanyList as $item){
            $collection->push((object)$item);
        }```

I cant use DB query, becouse i dont have this columns in DB, roughly speaking, these are added attributes